# how to create 2 python packages with a common namespace prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

is it possible for me to have 2 decoupled python packages where the first part of the namespace is identical:

pyPackageOne:

```
package_one
|
|-companyname
    |
    |-__init__py
    |-moduleone
        |
        |-__init__.py
        |-dostuff.py
```

pyPackageTwo:

```
package_two
|
|-companyname
    |
    |-__init__py
    |-moduletwo
        |
        |-__init__.py
        |-dothings.py
```

so companyname is a shared prefix in the name?

I want to be able to install and use both packages:

```
$ pip install moduleone
$ pip install moduletwo
>>> from companyname.moduleone import dostuff
>>> from companyname.moduletwo import dothings
```

I'm using python 3.6

Comment: I think your project stucture should work. Did you test if before asking a question here?

Comment: @Pax0r: I did but thanks to your comment I found my bug in the package, which I assumed had to do with the shared name. thanks!

Comment: @Pax0r the place where this strategy fails is when I try to use one package inside another: for example if dothings.py includes: `from companyname.moduleone import dostuff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Pax0r said in his comment, my original structure works.
see my minimal example:

https://github.com/omerholz/pymoduleone

https://github.com/omerholz/pymoduletwo

the place where this strategy fails is when I try to use one package inside another: for example if `dothings.py` includes: `from companyname.moduleone import dostuff`
we'll get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'companyname.moduleone'`